# How to unzip asynchronous way zip file in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

How do I unzip a file asynchronously? At the moment I am unzipping like this:

```
[SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:strZipFile toDestination:strDestPath];
```

But that blocks my main thread and the UI is unresponsive for longer than 10 seconds. The zip file is over 50MB, and I start the download in delegate on didFinishLaunching (to avoid long splash screen because it is not always necessary to have that file at the beginning.)

Comment: everything is asynchronous if you do it in another thread

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run it in a background thread using GCD:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:strZipFile toDestination:strDestPath];
 });
```

You might want to tell your app you've finished unzipping by calling a method somewhere in the main thread:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:strZipFile toDestination:strDestPath];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [someClass finishedUnzippingFile:strDestPath];
    });
 });
```